# Using case_when to calculate z_scores based on country

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is my code at the moment:

```
    z_adjusted <- demographics_cleaned %>%  
dplyr::filter(country_live == 'United States of America' | country_live == 'India' | country_live == 'United Kingdom'|country_live == 'Canada') %>% **##filtering only countries of interest** 
mutate(z_score_country = case_when(country_live == 'United Sates of America') ~ (money_per_month - US_m) / US_sd,  **##attempting to apply the Z score formula based on country**
(country_live == 'India') ~ (money_per_month - IN_m) / IN_sd), 
(country_live == 'Canada') ~ (money_per_month - CN_m) / CN_sd), 
(country_live == 'United Kingdom') ~ (money_per_month - UK_m) / UK_sd)
) %>%
arrange(desc(z_score_country))  **##arranging to find outliers e.t.c.**
```

I have calculated the means and sd's of the countries outside of this code and added them to the variables US_sd, US_m e.t.c.

I want to use case_when to perform the formula (value - sample mean) / sample SD and mutate this across the tibble

This does not seem to be working. I am wondering whether:

1. there is a better more elegant way to do this
2. this way will work if my code is correct

The error code I get is:

```
   Error: unexpected ',' in:
"    mutate(z_score_country = case_when(country_live == 'United Sates of America') ~ ((money_per_month - US_m) / US_sd),
           (country_live == 'India') ~ (money_per_month - IN_m) / IN_sd),"
> (country_live == 'Canada') ~ (money_per_month - CN_m) / CN_sd), 
Error: unexpected ')' in "(country_live == 'Canada') ~ (money_per_month - CN_m) / CN_sd)"
> (country_live == 'United Kingdom') ~ (money_per_month - UK_m) / UK_sd)
Error: unexpected ')' in "(country_live == 'United Kingdom') ~ (money_per_month - UK_m) / UK_sd)"
> ) %>%
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
>     arrange(desc(z_score_country))
Error in desc(z_score_country) : object 'z_score_country' not found
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. Try correcting to: `mutate(z_score_country = case_when((country_live == 'United Sates of America') ~ (money_per_month...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more easily with a grouped mutate, using the base `scale()` function. You can also use `%in%` to simplify your filter.

Finally, I would arrange by the *absolute value* of `z_score_country` to find both high and low outliers.

```
library(dplyr)

z_adjusted <- demographics_cleaned %>%  
  filter(country_live %in% c(
    'United States of America', 
    'India', 
    'United Kingdom', 
    'Canada'
  )) %>% 
  group_by(country_live) %>%
  mutate(z_score_country = scale(money_per_month)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(abs(z_score_country)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this was very helpful (and much cleaner to look at)!